# Can you round a number to a multiple of a number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m attempting a simple program in which rounding is required (to adjust for slightly different object weights). Can you say round ‘x’ (an input) to a multiple of ‘y’?

Not the actual code, but some background.

```
x = input(‘x input’)
y = int(input(‘y input’))
# round x to the nearest multiple of y
```

Comment: You can but there is nothing available for you in the Python standard library to do that directly. You have to write the logic yourself or use a library, e.g. [`num_align()` ](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/flyingcircus/src/cc20cd344b84194249fa25c667107ec848e64d90/flyingcircus/base.py#lines-4150) from [FlyingCircus](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = int(input("enter large number: x"))
y = int(input("Enter multiples: y"))

a = round(x/y)
b = a*y
print(b, " = x rounded to nearest multiple of y ")
```

Comment: you could cast them as float as well

Comment: Actually, you can cast `a` back to int, then b is also an int. No reason to go to float space here.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you say round ‘x’ (an input) to a multiple of ‘y’?

Yes -- by temporarily turning "multiples of `y`" into "multiples of 1" by dividing by `y`:

```
y * round(x / y)
```

(Note that, if you're using Python 2, you will need to replace `x` with `float(x)` to force floating-point division.)

Answer (score 0):

```
ind = 0
mult = 10  # Replace with desired
x = ...input

ind = round(x / mult)

low = abs( x - (mult * ind) )
high = abs( x - (mult * (ind + 1)) )

if low < high:
    return ind
else:
    return ind + 1
```

Comment: This appears to only be rounding up. Is there anyway I could modify it to round down too?

Comment: This rounds to the closest, above or below.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. Using a multiple of 7, an input of both 50 and 55 rounds to 56. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: Whoops! Off by one error. Fixed.

Comment: Wow, this is super convoluted. Any reason why simple `round()` wasn't incorporated? Also, having a `while` here seems super slow for larger numbers. Please remove the 'accepted' flag, this is horrible advice for future reference.

Comment: Made the suggested change. Feel free to make edits to answers as you see fit instead of criticizing them in comments!